# Right use of ProjecKey, ProjectName and Branch

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm not sure if I understand correctly the use of parameters ProjectKey, ProjectName and branch in a sonarscanner analysis.

Suppose that I have a project with diferents branches. When I run the analysis independently of the branch, the value for ProjectName and ProjectKey parameters has to be always the same?

Or every branch analysis must have a different project key? What is the best practices in that case?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters), sonar.branch section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sonar.projectKey` is an ID of the project. Example: if you will analyze project A and next project B with the same ID, then data of B will overwrite result stored for A project.

`sonar.projectName` is a display name - visible in SonarQube dashboard. Example: My Project

`sonar.branch` allows you to analyze more branches of one project. Example: if you analyze development branch of project A with ID equal to A, then SonarQube will create project A. Next if you analyze any branch of project A, then new data will overwrite previous results. But if you want to create a new project for other branch (instead of overwrite result for development branch), then you can use `sonar.branch` property which will generate a new ID (combined value of `sonar.projectKey` and `sonar.branch`)